# Simplifying a makefile

Tags: makefile

I have written a scary-looking Makefile by copy/pasting suggestions from Stack Overflow. However, I have read that it might not be necessary to provide explicit compiler invocations so many times (for example, the -O3 flag is everywhere). How can I simplify this Makefile?

```
CFLAGS = -Weverything -Wno-padded -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-conversion
all: fianchetto.o util.o ttable.o movegen.o
    clang -O3 $(CFLAGS) -D NDEBUG $^ -o fianchetto
debugf: fianchetto.o ttable.o movegen.o
    clang -O3 $(CFLAGS) -g3 $^ -o fianchetto
clean:
    rm *.o && rm *.gch & rm fianchetto && rm -rf fianchetto.dSYM
%.o: %.c
    clang -O3 -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
fianchetto.o: fianchetto.c
ttable.o: ttable.h ttable.c
movegen.o: movegen.h movegen.c
util.o: util.h util.c
```

I am mystified by a lot of the syntax, and would appreciate links or explanations of why simplifications work!

Comment: O3 flag: incorporate it into the CFLAGS macro.

Comment: You have a single `&` in your `clean` command; probably that should be `&&` as well, like the other ones?

Comment: Mostly what you have is okay, except for the repetition of the `.o` file names, and the hard-coded dependency rules (which also look like they might be incomplete: what, no C source file depends on any header file other than its own?) Dependencies are best compiler generated. You don't need them for a fresh rebuild, only for incremental rebuilds, and they can be obtained in the course of a rebuild.

Comment: "would appreciate links or explanations of why simplifications work!" please be more specific. Do you have a specific problem or question? Also, what have you already done researching Makefiles and their syntax? There is plenty of information that can help you understand this Makefile. Instead, you seem to have simply copy-pasted things without understanding; generally a bad idea. Please do some research first.

Comment: Note that since you only have one set of `.o` files, you cannot build the debug and release version at the same time. This could cause inconsistencies if you switch between debug and release, and some `.o` files get recompiled and others do not.  It's possible to have separate `.o` files for both ways of compiling, and separate executable names, like `fianchetto` and `fianchetto-dbg`.  That will complicate the Makefile rather than simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `CFLAGS` and defines (which should be in `CPPFLAGS` anyway) are useless when linking
- You're reinventing make's built-in rules, make will automatically link a target if one of its dependencies is "target.o" (in this case `fianchetto: fianchetto.o`). Make also knows how to compile C source files (as long as the source and object path match), so your pattern rule is superfluous too.
- The object prerequisites aren't necessary as both clang and GCC can generate dependencies for you with the `-M` set of flags.
- Compiling release and debug builds in the same dir makes for a more simple makefile, although you will need to remember to clean the object files when switching.
- By default make assigns `cc` to `CC`, and `cc` should be a link to your system's default compiler, so you might not even need the first line below

```
CC       := clang
CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP
CFLAGS   := -Weverything -Wno-padded -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-sign-conversion -O3

objs := fianchetto.o util.o ttable.o movegen.o
deps := $(objs:.o=.d)

.PHONY: all debugf clean
all:    CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
debugf: CFLAGS += -g3
all debugf: fianchetto 
fianchetto: $(objs)
clean: ; $(RM) $(objs) $(deps) fianchetto fianchetto.dSYM

-include $(deps)
```